# mysqld fails to start due to InnoDB

Tags: linux, server, mariadb-10.5

I did install MariaDB on MX Linux, my system info below :

```
System:    Kernel: 5.10.0-9-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64 
           root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm 4.16.1 vt: 7 
           dm: LightDM 1.26.0 Distro: MX-21_x64 Wildflower October 20  2021 
           base: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

When I start the server using the command :

sudo mysqld

I get the following error regarding InnoDB missing FILE_CHECKPOINT :

```
$ sudo mysqld
[sudo] password for ****: 
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.12-MariaDB-0+deb11u1) starting as process 14306 ...
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: 2 column families found
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: Column Families at start:
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]   cf=default
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     write_buffer_size=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     target_file_size_base=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]   cf=__system__
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     write_buffer_size=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note]     target_file_size_base=67108864
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: Table_store: loaded DDL data for 0 tables
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] RocksDB: global statistics using get_sched_indexer_t indexer
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] MyRocks storage engine plugin has been successfully initialized.
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=45118,45118
**2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT at 45118 between the checkpoint 45118 and the end 108246.**
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2022-02-22  0:00:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-02-22  0:00:19 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It is beyond my competences, can anyone give me some hint ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-recovery.html try to follow this guide.

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry about the wrong place, I will seek for help on ServerFault.